# Why is a windows domain user required and is there an alternative?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2019

I have a script that executes JAVA program. The script runs fine under my own user.

However, the script fails to run when using a scheduler service, which runs on the same (EC2) machine, under a system account with administrator privileges (`SchedulerUser`).

My supplier tells me I need to run the scheduler service using a domain user.

This would require me to set up an Active Directory, which I like to prevent if possible.

Why is a windows domain user required for this, and is there an alternative?

Comment: Being a Windows domain user is not a requirement to be able to use the scheduler. I suggest you ask your supplier.

Comment: The alternative would be to use a regular user. Just try it.

Comment: `Why is a windows domain user required for this` what was the vendor's response to this question?

Comment: @GregAskew : 'This is because we need to access the file 'ws_repo_locations.xml' in %UserProfile%\WhereScape\3D. This file has the information needed to connect to the metadata database and can't be accessed when using a service user. '

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to gain a better understanding about what went wrong: start your script as system account interactively.
1 download pstools from Microsoft
2 extract them and copy psexec.exe to yur c:\windows directory
3 right click cmd.exe and select "run as administrator" to get an elevated shell
4 on that elevated shell, run
psexec -si cmd
to get a shell that runs as system account. On that shell, execute your script and share the output.

Comment: I tried `psexec -si powershell  -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Users\Bart\Documents\GitHub\wherescape-warehouse\powershell\3D\Unlock_3D_Objects.ps1` 

when run from a powershell window as `SchedulerUser` it says : 

`Couldn't install PSEXESVC service:
Access is denied.`

Comment: @Bernd Schwanenmeister: this would be a good suggestion, but the system account is not being used, it is a local account.

Comment: If you are not allowed to install the psexec service, you are not running the command shell elevated. Do as suggested. Greg's saying that you are not using the system account, ok, what happens if you do (change executing user to "system")?

Comment: When I run the same in a powershell that i opened with `Run as Administrator` I just get `powershell exited on EC2AMAZ-8RCMO7R with error code 0.`

Comment: I tried starting the scheduler service with both `system` and `LocalSystem` as users, but that did not work

Comment: OK, also tried to run onther script that has the same issue. with the risk of getting sidetracked..... : When I run `psexec -si powershell  -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Users\Bart\Documents\GitHub\wherescape-warehouse\powershell\3D\Create_3D_backup.ps1` a dos box appears with an error   'sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2 getDesktop WARNING Cannot Access 'Desktop' java.io.IOException: Could not get shell folder ID list at .... .... Exception in thread "Main" java.lang.NullPointerException'.